# Not able to understand on which line the lint error is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint

I have git action to check lint errors. i see below error on git action. although i have eslint plugin installed on my vscode, which shows no error. Can anyone tell on which line this error is ?(1***8 means 1 to 8 ?) I have imports till 8 lines.

```
 1***8:25  error  Do not nest ternary expressions  no-nested-ternary
 ✖ 1 problem (1 error, *** warnings)
```

Comment: I would guess line 8. But the error message is quite clear, too - you have a nested conditional operator. The error is wherever you have that.

Comment: Okay i found it. thanks @VLAZ

Comment: I wonder why nested ternaries throw a linting error. Ternaries are supposed to be more efficient and "memory" friendly to my knowledge. I once so a video on youtube of someone showing actual performance benefits coding with ternaries only. It was in C though..

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou "*I wonder why nested ternaries throw a linting error.*" Because the rule has been enabled: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-nested-ternary ESLint is configurable. "*Ternaries are supposed to be more efficient and "memory" friendly to my knowledge.*" that is false "*I once so a video on youtube of someone showing actual performance benefits coding with ternaries only. It was in C though..*" Not valid for JS but I doubt that's the case in general. I don't see why `int x; if (cond) x = 1 else x = 2` wouldn't be optimised to be more efficient by the compiler

Comment: I think it had to do with minimizing word count along with spaces, line breaks etc.. Anyway it's been a while since I saw that.